# "Dialog failed with unknown" error response . Facebook app invite, on switch of fb account

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-app-invites

I am having an error in Android facebook app invite. Everything was working fine. I switched the account from Facebook and now I am getting this error.

```
if(AppInviteDialog.canShow()) {
                AppInviteContent content = new AppInviteContent.Builder()
                        .setApplinkUrl(VPPreferences.getString(VPPreferencesKeys.INVITE_SCREEN_URL_FOR_FB, ""))
                        .setPreviewImageUrl(getString(R.string.invite_fbimage_url))
                        .build();


                AppInviteDialog appInviteDialog = new AppInviteDialog(this);
                 sCallbackManager = CallbackManager.Factory.create();

                appInviteDialog.registerCallback(sCallbackManager, new FacebookCallback<AppInviteDialog.Result>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(AppInviteDialog.Result result) {
                        ToastNotificationUtil.showMessageToast(InviteSelectorScreen.this, getString(R.string.invite_succ));
                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onCancel() {
                        ToastNotificationUtil.showMessageToast(InviteSelectorScreen.this, "Invite canceled");

                    }

                    @Override
                    public void onError(FacebookException e) {
                        ToastNotificationUtil.showMessageToast(InviteSelectorScreen.this, "Invite failed ");

                    }
                });

                appInviteDialog.show(content);
            }
```

Comment: share the logcat error too

Comment: There is no error in logical .

Comment: code just compiles on error returning this “Dialog failed with unknown”  in e

Comment: Hi dude i am also getting same error message , Previously it was working fine.

Comment: May be there is a change in fb SDK . It was woking fine for me but suddenly this error is showing .

Comment: Which FB SDK version do you use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Quoting from [Facebook Developers](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.11/page/feed#custom-image) there is a major change in their policy.

> As of November 7, 2017, link customization is available however the
>   link must be owned by the posting page and a page access token is
>   required.
>
> To verify ownership, check the
>   ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts} field on the URL node.
>   You must call this endpoint before posting new links.
>
> Without this
>   step, custom link page posts will not work for un-scraped links. See
>   our Link Ownership Guide for more information.
>
> For versions 2.10 and
>   lower, picture, name, thumbnail, and description are deprecated.
>   caption is deprecated for all versions.

Please go to the given link and change check the ownership_permissions{can_customize_link_posts} field on the URL node.

Hope this helps

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue Hamza, what I found is this:

As the latest release of Facebook SDK version 4.28.0 - November 7, 2017, App Invites is deprecated. https://developers.facebook.com/docs/app-invites/android/

> With the release of the Facebook SDK version 4.28.0, App Invites is
>   deprecated. It will be supported until February 5, 2018.

I think the solution is to use another way to allow your users share your app with its friends like [firebase dynamic links](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase).

Hope it helps